# How to pass map from java to javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, json, ajax, jsp

I have a drop down list and an info tooltip icon beside it, when the user changes the value in the drop down then hover to the info icon, a description for the selection should appear  ... as in figure :

[image]

Now I have a map of values in the backend where key is the drop down value and value is the description, I want this map to be available to the front end (javascript) , I have many options :

1- on each value change make an ajax call (not good since many calls to the backend with no need as the map is actually static)

2- pass the map as a json object to some html hidden element and then read it ... but the problem was in escaping quotes and other similar stuff in json before setting it to the html element

3- use data attribute  .... but the framework I am working on does not support HYML5

4- make one ajax call after page load, read the json and putting it in javascript var .... but again a useless request to the back-end

5- make a global variable in my JSP (using declaration element) .... but this is not thread safe and will cause me to use scriplets

I went to the fifth solution because the map is static and has no much problem with concurrency .... more over the framework I am working on is entirely written with scriplets

Do any one has other recommendation from the solution I mentioned or any other solution ....

Comment: `make one ajax call after page load [...] but again a useless request to the back-end` I don't know about your situation, but I wouldn't really worry about this. If you are going to put it in the HTML dynamically, then it's going to be "useless processing by the back-end" as well. Pretty much anything you do that will somehow walk/transform the map and hand it over to the client side will be "useless" in the grand scheme of things, since the map will be static. The only way to save yourself that is to either add the data staticly to the HTML or...to not worry about it until it's a problem.

Answer (score 0):

> 2- pass the map as a json object to some html hidden element and then read it ... but the problem was in escaping quotes and other similar stuff in json before setting it to the html element

You can easily solve this problem by using `JSON.stringify()` and later `JSON.parse()`.

So I suggest to use that approach - stringify the json object and put it in an element, then you can just parse the data.

```js
var obj = {foo: 'bar', arr: ['baz','foobar']};

var el = document.getElementById('jsonData');

// setting the value here -- you would do this in your jsp template
el.setAttribute('data-json', JSON.stringify(obj));

console.log(JSON.parse(el.getAttribute('data-json')));
```

```html
<div style="display:none" id="jsonData"></div>
```

Comment: Why not simply use a `var data` instead of a DOM element ? Is there any benefits I don't see ?

Comment: as I told you , first my framework doesn't support HTML5, thus the data attribute can't be used safely

second the map is created initially in java and I want to pass it to frontend and not vice-versa

Comment: when I put the jsonobject inside either `document.getElementById('jsonData').setAttribute('json-data',JSON.stringify(obj)); `
or `document.getElementById('jsonData').value =JSON.stringify(obj)` .. It's  corrupted

Comment: No it's not corrupted. Why should it? @osamayaccoub  . Also you wouldn't use setElement, as you said you want to populate the elements content by Java.

Comment: json object is like this {"xxx":"yyy" ....} ...... so when I put it in attribute json-data , then json-data="{"xxx":"yyy" ....}" ..... which is finally translated to json-data="{" because of the double qoutes

Comment: ah, so you just didn't care to try my complete answer... Use JSON.parse() as I've described in the answer... @osamayaccoub

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach.

1. Generate mirror DOM elements for each option.By default those are hidden.
2. When in the Onchange event of select box or mouse over event of tooltip icon process the message and show.

For JSP loop you can have again 2 approaches. Those are Value and index of select box.

1.you can use value field of combobox(dropdown list/html select) as : ${c.id}

2.you can use loop index as : ${cStatus.index}

```
<c:forEach items="${somethingList}" var="c" varStatus="cStatus">        
    <input type="hidden" id="hiddenToolTip${${cStatus.index}" value="you have selected XXX. XXX is blah blah blah">
 </c:forEach>
```

After that in mouse over event of tooltip function:

You can read current selected option selected index or selected value and read value from hidden field
and display tooltip.

```
var tooltipText=document.getElementById("hiddenToolTip"+ document.getElementById("comboBoxId").value ).value;
alert("here is tooltip text="+tooltipText);
```